# How to get help on methods in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

whenever I use `help()` on a method I get a weird looking output. 
For example, `help(obj.readline)` gives me the following output:

```
Help on built-in function readline:

readline(...)
```

That's all i get. I don't know how to interpret it.Why there is no description about the method? Can somebody please explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Is this weird output?

```
>>> f = open('data.txt')
>>> help(f.readline)
Help on built-in function readline:

readline(...)
    readline([size]) -> next line from the file, as a string.

    Retain newline.  A non-negative size argument limits the maximum
    number of bytes to return (an incomplete line may be returned then).
    Return an empty string at EOF.
```